# how to make fewer http requests

Tags: javascript, files, performance

I'm use YSlow to optimize my web pages it says:
This page has 34 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
This page has 5 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one.
but all I have in this page is some blocks and menus and a nivo slider which I think is the main reason of this issue!!
so I think nivo slider sends all this requests!!
How can I improve it?

Comment: 34 javascript files sounds like a lot, maybe you could just enable core CSS & JS aggregation at admin > config > development > performance.

Comment: those are enable!!

Answer (score 3):

There are couple of things you can do,

1. install [labjs](https://www.drupal.org/project/labjs) module: it is a JavaScript loader, used by Twitter, Vimeo, examiner.com... which loads (and executes) all scripts in parallel as fast as the browser will allow.
2. Enable gzip compression: It reduces the size of files sent from server to increase the speed. You have to enable it in `.htaccess` file, for more information visit [this page.](http://gtmetrix.com/enable-gzip-compression.html)
3. As @2pha said `Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation` is very effective effort.
4. Install [optimize_db](https://www.drupal.org/project/optimizedb) module: it handles the issue with fast-growing table cache_form.

Anyway, [gtmetrix](http://gtmetrix.com)  suggests many techniques to improve your website performance.

Comment: thanks a lot! I should choose one of this suggestions or I must do all of theme in parallel?

Comment: Use all of the in parallel.

Comment: thanks Drupalist. these approaches helped in other ways but doesn't reduce the external http requests!

Answer (score 1):

What have you tried already?
I use the [Advanced CSS/JS Aggregation](https://www.drupal.org/project/advagg) module which combines js and css file together making for fewer http requests. It also has some other features including moving js and css to the footer.

Comment: I've tried to combine all css files together. same for js files. but I afraid making a worse trouble anyway. have you tested this module?

Comment: I have used this module on over 30 sites. My answer is specific to JS, there are many other optimizations one can do to speed up a drupal site. Doing a quick search on google for 'drupal perfomance' will yield many results

Comment: before installing or enabling this module you should uncheck css/js aggregation in performance setting. otherwise your theme will be vanished. this happened for me and I was furious!

Comment: This page has 12 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
This page has 31 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one. why it get worse using this module?

Comment: You are setting it up wrong. Did you read the [readme](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/advagg/tree/README.txt) file?

Comment: This page has 17 external Javascript scripts. Try combining them into one.
This page has 37 external stylesheets. Try combining them into one. why it does not change after lots of setting?

Comment: How can we know? We cant see your site. Do you have external scripts? These can not be aggregated.

Comment: this is my website url http://www.etgmco.ir/pilot-project/ppr-2

Comment: Viewing the source, javascript and css is being included on the page with `@import`. This says to me that you have not checked the options under 'bandwidth optimisation' page at: admin/config/development/performance. These checkboxes need to be selected.

Comment: this is the main problem 2pha! when I enable theme my theme vanishes and none of the js run!! what should I do? I need urgent help please